# Strange behaviour when minimizing virtualbox in fullscreen mode

Tags: 12.04, unity, virtualbox, fullscreen

I have the same problem like mentioned in this thread.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12257698

> When virtualbox is running in fullscreen mode, and I'll minimize it to
>   go back to Unity, the only visible elements are the wallpaper and the
>   background shadow of the upper bar. If then I click on virtualbox main
>   window return all normal. I want to report a bug, but I don't know if
>   is Unity or Virtualbox issue. Thanks in advance!

I think it exists since unity update yesterday (or day before yesterday).

Any ideas?
If you need more information tell me please.

I use ubuntu 12.04 host an Win7 guest.

Graphics: Intel® Sandybridge Mobile

Comment: Hm, weird. When I double-click the minimize button virtualbox window minmize correctly!?!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's a bug in Unity since a recent update. I've started experiencing it about a month ago with the full screen writing app Focuswriter and I've found out that it happens when any full screen program on my system is minimized.

I've filed this bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1069451

If you confirm it, maybe they will do something about it ...

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanx for your reply. I confirmed the bug, although, it doesn't affect me on 12.10, only on 12.04 LTS.